# Trying implement builder function with slice in rust

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying implement builder function:

```
extern crate debug;


use std::mem::size_of_val;


#[deriving(Show, PartialEq)]
pub struct A<'a> {
    pub a: &'a [i64],
    pub b: &'a str,
}


fn build<'a>() -> A<'a> {
    return A { a: &[1,2,3], b: "test" };
}


fn main() {
    let a = build();
    println!("{} - {} - `{:?}`", a, size_of_val(&a), a);
}
```

But this give me next compile error:

```
/prsrc/main.rs:16:20: 16:27 error: borrowed value does not live long enough
/prsrc/main.rs:16         return A { a: &[1,2,3], b: "test" };
                                         ^~~~~~~
/prsrc/main.rs:15:25: 17:2 note: reference must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 15:24...
/prsrc/main.rs:15     fn build<'a>() -> A<'a> {
/prsrc/main.rs:16         return A { a: &[1,2,3], b: "test" };
/prsrc/main.rs:17     }
/prsrc/main.rs:16:5: 16:41 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the statement at 16:4; consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
/prsrc/main.rs:16         return A { a: &[1,2,3], b: "test" };
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I even try `A { a: [1,2,3], b: "test" }`, `A { a: &'a [1,2,3], b: "test" }` and `std:rc:Rc::new(A { a: &[1,2,3], b: "test" })` but it still not work.

When I replace `&[i64]` to `Vec<i64>`:

```
fn build<'a>() -> A<'a> {
    return A { a: vec![1,2,3], b: "test" };
}
```

all work right:

```
A { a: [1, 2, 3], b: test } - 40 - `A<'static>{a: collections::vec::Vec<i64>{len: 3u, cap: 4u, ptr: (0x7f1097426000 as *mut ())}, b: "test"}`
```

I little confused because as I understand `&[i64]` implementation should be similar to `&str` and `str` work when I replace `&[i64]` to `Vec<i64>`.

So how can I implement builder function for slice?

Comment: libdebug and `{:?}` is gone now, by the way.

Comment: Just update with `rustup.sh` - still working and no warning that deprecated.

Comment: You are not invoking a fresh build of Rust, whether you’ve run `rustup.sh` or not. libdebug has been completely gone for some days.

Comment: Ok, look like when I install `rustup.sh --prefix=/path` then `/path/bin/cargo` use just `rustc` instead `/path/bin/rustc`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint that something is wrong with your lifetimes is here :

```
fn build<'a>() -> A<'a> { /* ... */ }
```

You have an output lifetime, but no input lifetime.

The only way this is possible is if your lifetime is in fact `'static`, as otherwise it *must* be linked to at least one of the arguments, which defines it.

So your function should in fact be of type :

```
fn build() -> A<'static>
```

But here comes the problem : your two references *must* thus link to static storage. You are lucky, `&str` is a special case here. String literals (`"test"` in your case) are *always* in static storage. So far so good.

But `&[1,2,3]` is not in static storage. In fact, this shortcut is equivalent to :

```
let temp = [1,2,3];
return A { a: &temp, b: "test" };
```

and now, the lifetime issue becomes obvious.

The fix is quite simple : make the temporary variable explicitly `'static`, like this :

```
fn build() -> A<'static> {                    //'
    static temp: [i64, ..3] = [1,2,3];
    return A { a: &temp, b: "test" };
}
```

Comment: Note: the alternative is to pass the slice as a parameter to `build`, thus deducing the lifetime: `fn build<'a>(slice: &'a [i64]) -> A<'a>`

Comment: @Levans, so in this case variable `temp` will be static and will free only program end. For my case it should get data from http or file with huge size of data. Currently look like that `Vec` and `String` is better for this but for immutable data it have unnecessary capacity. However interesting can I do this for slices and str?

Comment: @tbicr When using slices and str, you need to have something else to own the data. The real question between Vec and a slice is not about capacity but rather about where the data is stored. If it's your A struct that will store it, you have to use Vec and String.